# Returning rvalue references

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I've seen other posts regarding this but I'm still quite a bit confused regarding this.

```
const std::string& func(std::string&& ref) { return ref; }

int main(void) {
  const std::string& r=func("E");
  std::cout << r << std::endl;
}
```

Now this should technically be UB, I'm returning a reference to `"E"` which should be destroyed after the expression that assigns to `r` is done, right? However, no warning from clang or g++, perhaps I am missing something?

```
const std::string& func(std::string ref) { return ref; }

int main(void) {
  const std::string& r=func("E");
  std::cout << r << std::endl;
}
```

Clang would warn about something like this.
But, it doesn't warn about this:

```
const std::string& func(std::string ref) { return std::move(ref); }

int main(void) {  
  const std::string& r=func("E");
  std::cout << r << std::endl;  
}
```

It also doesn't warn about something like:

```
std::string&& func(std::string&& ref) { return std::move(ref); }

int main(void) {
  std::string&& r=func("E");
  std::cout << r << std::endl;  
}
```

Is this not UB after all?

If someone could clarify on these I'd be grateful.

Comment: Just because the program will have obvious undefined behavior to a human, places upon the compiler no obligation whatsoever. If it can figure it out and warn you about it, great. If not, that's unfortunate.

Comment: @0RR The last one is UB too.

Comment: So.. a bit of an extra but in which case is it legal to return rvalue references?

Comment: @pol You can return an rvalue reference as long as you know that the object referred to is still alive. Or if you are using it in an unevaluated context. `std::declval` comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, no warning from clang or g++, perhaps I am missing something?

Only thing that you're missing is the fact that compilers are not guaranteed nor required to warn about undefined behaviour and generally are not able to do so.

> Is this not UB after all?

The behaviour of the program **is** undefined. Lack of a warning is not proof of well defined behaviour.

---

For what it's worth, both GCC and Clang detect this bug at runtime with AddressSanitizer.

Comment: Thank you, I was a bit worried I was missing something. I know it's not a good idea to determine whether something is UB or not based on compiler's behaviour, I figured perhaps it was doing something else.